# How to disable auto charge when my iPad plugged into my Mac?

Tags: ipad, mac

Whenever I plugged my iPad into my Mac, it will auto charge. For some reasons, I wanna turn this feature off. Is there anyway to do it? I searched but only got not revalent answers.

Comment: It should be possible, but don't know about MacOS. The host will have to tell the IPad that there is not enough power available. However I am wondering why you would want to do it. Is there a problem with your MAC?

Answer (score 3):

Plug it in to a USB hub.  When my ipad is connected directly it charges, but when its plugged in to a hub thats connected the ipad reads "Not Charging" next to the battery icon.

Comment: This notice happens when the iPad is not acquiring enough power from the charging supply to charge the iPad, but keep in mind the distinction between not charging and not receiving any power at all — the iPad will still draw power from the computer, likely keeping the iPad battery at a similar level instead of decreasing with use.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.
The only way this could be possible would be through disabling output charge from your Mac, but that's not possible either as far as I know. 
Another possible way would be to use a special kind of USB cable which allows data exchange without charging the device.

Answer (score 1):

I looked around for a "data only cable" or one where you could "disable charging," and found nothing online that seemed relevant. It may be possible to have a ["data sync only" with a Nokia device](http://www.dx.com/p/usb-data-cable-for-nokia-n97-n85-5230-c5-03-5800-e72-e63-96cm-length-80611#.V8DSPaOZPEY), but not an Apple device.

I found articles describing altering the 8-pin, but those resulted in shorting and other problems, so this is not advisable.

I also identified no apps that disable charging in the iOS App Store.

On thing you could do is turn on iTunes wi-fi syncing. Plug your iPad into your computer. Open iTunes. Click the checkbox that enables wi-fi syncing under "Options."

My iPad Pro says that it has to be plugged in to sync automatically, but I was able to do it manually without it being plugged in. Just go to General > iTunes Wi-Fi Sync > Sync Now.

[image: WiFi Sync]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but if anyone comes looking for it, I found a trick that seems to work if both devices have USB-C.

Take a USB-C to USB-A cable and a USB-A to USB-C dongle. Then connect the dongle end to the iPad and the USB-C end to the Mac. That way, the iPad will behave as the host in the USB protocol, so the Mac won't charge it (and the iPad doesn't supply enough power to charge the Mac).

If anyone is wondering "why would you ever do this?", my use case is when using SideCar — it makes no sense to drain power from the laptop when the iPad is perfectly able to last hours on its own battery. Apparently it works for SideCar, but not for syncing via Finder. I put the iPad in Airplane mode to make sure it's not fallbacking to wi-fi.